# How to pass express header as a string to a function using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

We are making a GraphQL API writing TypeScript and I'm trying to pass an express header's value to a function that expects `string` input. Here's my code:

```
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from "express";
import { UserResolver } from "./../resolvers/UserResolver";

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
  const uid = req.headers.uid;
  const { findByShibbolethUid } = new UserResolver();

  const user = findByShibbolethUid(uid);

  next();
};
```

My problem is that Typescript says the variable `uid` is of type `string | string[]` and will not accept it as an argument. If I mock `req.headers.uid = "123"` and then print out `uid[0]`, I get `"1"` confirming that the header value is what I expect, a single string.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You're not dealing with the fact that it could be a string *or* an array of strings.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I guess my question is a bit unclear. What I’m worried about is that I’ve made a mistake somewhere else and the result is that type. So should a header always be of type `string | string[]`? If so, then I’ll just happily handle the optional type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle the second type in the union.

```
if (typeof uid === 'string') {
  user = findByShibbolethUid(uid);
} else {
  user = findByShibbolethUid(uid[0]);
  // Or handle all the supplied uids. Or fail.
}
```

The header field will be an array in case multiple copies of the same header are supplied in the request.